# Data race detector - OPENMP

Tags: c++, openmp, race-condition, data-race

I am new to the OPENMP game so I am currently using a race detector tool to test my skills. 
I wrote the following code using OPENMP sections:

```
#include "omp.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N        10000
#define Nthreads 2
int randy = 1; 
double sum = 0.0;

void function1()
{
   int i, length =8; 
   printf("function1 thread id: %d", omp_get_thread_num());
   for (i=0;i<length;i++) {
     randy =i;
    }   
}

void function2()
{
   int i;  
   for(i=0; i< 5; i++)
   {
    sum +=i;
    }
   printf("function2 thread id: %d", omp_get_thread_num());
}

int main()
{  
  int numthreads, flag = 0, flg_tmp;
  omp_set_num_threads(Nthreads);
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
     #pragma omp sections
     {
        #pragma omp section
        {
           function2();
        }
        #pragma omp section
        {
           function1();
        }
      }
  }   
}
```

I am getting data race errors for the variables sum and randy.They are global variables. I don't really get why it is detecting them as race-error. However, when I declare them inside the functions instead of globally, I don't get race errors. Can someone please explain why?

Statements by the tool:

==== Found a race between: 
Shared variable:

```
     17|double sum = 0.0;
Thread 1:

 33|   for(i=0; i< 5; i++)
 34|   {
> 35|    sum +=i;
 36|    }
 37|   printf("function2 thread id: %d", omp_get_thread_num());

Thread 2:

 33|   for(i=0; i< 5; i++)
 34|   {
>  35|    sum +=i;
 36|    }
 37|   printf("function2 thread id: %d", omp_get_thread_num());


==== Found a race between: 


  6|int randy = 1; 
    Thread 1:
     23|   printf("function1 thread id: %d", omp_get_thread_num());
     24|   for (i=0;i<length;i++) {
 >   25|     randy =i;
     26|    }   
     27|}
    Thread 2:
     23|   printf("function1 thread id: %d", omp_get_thread_num());
     24|   for (i=0;i<length;i++) {
>    25|     randy =i;
     26|    }   
     27|}
```

Comment: What happens if both threads try to modify `randy` at the same time? That's what a data race is.

Comment: But I am using sections, so shouldn't it mean that only one thread is executing this section?

Comment: OK, maybe I don't know OMP syntax as well as you do.

Comment: Quoting from the OpenMP spec, "Each structured block is executed once by one of the threads in the team in the context of its implicit task."  That is, you would expect that the two sections may be executed simultaneously, with one thread executing each section.  With that in mind, I'd suggest returning to Adrian's comment and giving it further consideration.

Comment: I guess I am stupid because I  still don't get how this is considered a race. Function 1 modifies `randy` and function 2 modifies `sum`. To my understanding of `OpenMP sections` and as you said, the sections can be executed simultaneously but each section is executed by only one thread. Do you mean two threads can execute the same section? or do you mean they can switch threads between sections while executing? I am genuinely confused. Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: What tool is this? Looks like false positive to me.

Comment: I missed that you have two different functions (each referencing a different global variable) in the two sections.  Given that, I think you're correct.

Comment: Yes, I think it is false positive as well. Thanks!

Comment: This might be caused by the two variables sharing a single cache line. Out of curiosity - what happens if you add some padding between the two variables? Like: `int randy = 1; 
char pad[128]; double sum = 0.0;`